# "Cannot call value of non-function type"

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have just downloaded the Xcode 8 Beta so that I can include some of the new iOS 10 frameworks in my app. However, during the process of converting my code from Swift 2 to Swift 3, I ran into several errors. I fixed all but one super annoying one.

I am getting the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'JSQMessagesCollectionView!' at the following line of code:

```
let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
```

Here is my entire function for context:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.senderId == senderId {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    return cell
}
```

Does anybody have an ideas?

P.s. If this helps, here is my entire block of code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import JSQMessagesViewController

class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    var messages = [JSQMessage]()
    var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!
    var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!

    var userIsTypingRef: FIRDatabaseReference! // 1
    private var localTyping = false // 2
    var isTyping: Bool {
        get {
            return localTyping
        }
        set {
            // 3
            localTyping = newValue
            userIsTypingRef.setValue(newValue)
        }
    }
    var usersTypingQuery: FIRDatabaseQuery!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Change the navigation bar background color to blue.
        // navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red:252/255, green: 87/255, blue: 68/255, alpha: 1)
        navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red:250/255, green: 69/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1)


        title = "RoastChat"
        setupBubbles()
        // No avatars
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSize.zero

        // Remove file upload icon
        self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

        messageRef = rootRef.child("messages")
    }

    func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        observeMessages()
        observeTyping()
    }

  func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
  }


    func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                                 messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
        return messages[indexPath.item]
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                                 messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
        let message = messages[indexPath.item] // 1
        if message.senderId == senderId { // 2
            return outgoingBubbleImageView
        } else { // 3
            return incomingBubbleImageView
        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                                 avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
        return nil
    }

    private func setupBubbles() {
        let factory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
        outgoingBubbleImageView = factory?.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(
            // UIColor.init(red:250/255, green: 69/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1))
            with: UIColor.init(red:47/255, green: 53/255, blue: 144/255, alpha: 1))

        incomingBubbleImageView = factory?.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(
            with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGray())
    }

    func addMessage(id: String, text: String) {
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: id, displayName: "", text: text)
        messages.append(message!)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        if message.senderId == senderId {
            cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!,
                                     senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {

        let itemRef = messageRef.childByAutoId() // 1
        let messageItem = [ // 2
            "text": text,
            "senderId": senderId
        ]
        itemRef.setValue(String(messageItem)) // 3

        // 4
        JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()

        // 5
        finishSendingMessage()

        isTyping = false

    }

    private func observeMessages() {
        // 1
        let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast: 25)
        // 2
        messagesQuery.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
            // 3
            let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
            let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String

            // 4
            self.addMessage(id: id, text: text)

            // 5
            self.finishReceivingMessage()
        }
    }

    private func observeTyping() {
        let typingIndicatorRef = rootRef.child("typingIndicator")
        userIsTypingRef = typingIndicatorRef.child(senderId)
        userIsTypingRef.onDisconnectRemoveValue()

        // 1
        usersTypingQuery = typingIndicatorRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true)

        // 2
        usersTypingQuery.observe(.value) { (data: FIRDataSnapshot!) in

            // 3 You're the only typing, don't show the indicator
            if data.childrenCount == 1 && self.isTyping {
                return
            }

            // 4 Are there others typing?
            self.showTypingIndicator = data.childrenCount > 0
            self.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
        }
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        super.textViewDidChange(textView)
        // If the text is not empty, the user is typing
        isTyping = textView.text != ""
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> AttributedString! {
        return AttributedString(string:"test")
    }

}
```

Comment: You can edit your post, so "delete and re-post" is not a good way. And, again, don't you have a property like `var collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!` in your class?

Comment: Sorry about that. Something happened on my network and I thought something went wrong with my post

Comment: Also, no I do not have any property like that

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code. You are saying `JSQMessagesCollectionView` somewhere but you are not showing us where.

Comment: Written in Objective-C where this was not an issue, the `JSQMessagesViewController` class has a property called `collectionView`, which is shadowing the `collectionView()` method. I don't know how to refer to one vs. the other clearly; in Swift you can't even define a property with the same name as a method.

Comment: I have updated my post with my entire class for context. Also, this is JSQMessagesViewController: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: Remove let cell = super..., and init your cell properly.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan, how would I init my cell properly?

Comment: Did you hear about reuse id technic?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan no...

Comment: @andyvn22 Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the method as:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.senderId == senderId {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    return cell
}
```

If you are writing an overridden method correctly, Swift complains about missing `override` keyword. So, if you cannot find any warnings or errors on this overridden method, you are very likely misusing method signature.

And many `UICollectionViewDataSource`s methods are renamed, in Swift3 "cellForItemAtIndexPath" has this signature:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

So, Swift cannot find a method definition matching `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`, so assuming the `collectionView` there would be a property. (Unfortunately, it is declared in `JSQMessagesViewController`.)

You may have this sort of mismatching method implementations in your class. Better check them all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how to create and reuse cell properly:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("reuseId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    //update cell subviews here 
    return cell
}
```

In your case you should create and return `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell` instance

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("reuseId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
```

Comment: How will this help me in the context of my problem?